# HTML parsing with python regular expression

Tags: python, html, regex

I am using python regular expression to parse html file, now I need to extract a number from a html tag, the number can be either integer or floating point value. Following are two examples:

integer case:

```
<span class='addr-bbs'>2 baths</span>
```

floating point case:

```
<span class='addr-bbs'>3.5 baths</span>
```

My original code is:

```
bath = re.findall('<span class=\"addr_bbs\">' + '(.{1,3})' + 'baths{0,1}<', str(homedata))
```

But after testing, it misses all the floating point cases. How can I cover both cases to extract the number correctly?

Thanks

Comment: Don't use regex to parse html, use a html parser.

Comment: Please don't parse HTML with regex, it's gonna hurt you. You're using Python already, why not use BeautifulSoup? https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented, use a [html parser](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) to find the tags by *class name*. If the number is always the first in the text you can just split to extract it once you have the tag:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
h = """<span class='addr-bbs'>3.5 baths</span>
      <span class='addr-bbs'>1 baths</span>
      <span class='foos'>3.0 baths</span>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(h,"html.parser")

for span in soup.select("span.addr-bbs"):
    print(span.text.split()[0])
```

Which would print:

```
3.5
1
```

If you want to also filter by the tag text, i.e there are other spans with the `addr-bbs`, you can pass a regex to [find_all](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#calling-a-tag-is-like-calling-find-all) to only get the *span.addr-bbs* that have the word *baths*.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
h = """<span class='addr-bbs'>3.5 baths</span>
"<span class='addr-bbs'>5 rooms</span>
      <span class='addr-bbs'>1 baths</span>
      <span class='foos'>3.0 baths</span>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(h, "html.parser")

for span in soup.find_all("span","addr-bbs", text=re.compile(r"\bbaths\b")):
    print(span.text.split()[0])
```

Comment: You are probably right, regx may not be a good idea in a long terms. I need to redo the whole thing with BeautifulSoup.

Answer (score 0):

Three typos:

- the inverted commas;
- the dash;
- the space.

Try with `bath = re.findall('''<span class=["']addr-bbs["']>''' + '(.{1,3})' + ' baths{0,1}<', str(homedata))`

Answer (score 0):

First, realize you are somewhat doomed without more processing.  Some realtors will write "2.5", others "2 1/2", others "2+1/2", and so on.   MLS
data has never normalized, in part to make it difficult to parse.  Just when you think you have it solved, you get "2+sink".  It's usually permissible to guess the numeric meaning for searches and then spit out the original text when its displayed.

You should probably grab everything from the `>` to `baths`.  To do this correctly, you should use the "non-greedy" modify, so that you don't parse
all the way down to the next record.   You can read non-greedy in thsi [Python doc](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html#greedy-versus-non-greedy), but the magic phrase is:

`bath = re.findall('<span class=\"addr_bbs\">(.*?)bath.?<', str(homedata))`

Then try to parse bath.groups() best you can.